# What is wrong with my httpd.conf file?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I am using Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10. The real domain name has been obfuscated to `example.com` for this question.

I am attempting to set `AllowOverride` to `None`. I currently have an `.htaccess` file in my `DocumentRoot`. This is what it looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # deal with php5-cgi first
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>

        # for normal Apache installations
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

        # for Apache FGCI installations
        <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

I ran `phpinfo()` to determine that my `Server API` is `Apache 2.0 Handler`. This makes me think that the rewrite rule that I need is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`. Is that correct?

I tried to move this rewrite rule into my `sites-available/example.com` configuration file, but whenever I set `AllowOverride` to `None`, I end up with a 500 error.

This is what my `example.com` configuration file looked like before:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /httpd/www/example.com/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /httpd/www/example.com/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The above configuration works fine. I attempted to merge the contents of my `.htaccess` file into my `sites-available/example.com` file. The results look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /httpd/www/example.com/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /httpd/www/example.com/public>
                Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Oh wow. What a n00b. Do you see what I did wrong? I sure do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if I put the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives in the correct order (`RewriteCond` comes **BEFORE** `RewriteRule`)...yeah, that helps.